# Trouble accesing JSON file with angular

Tags: html, angularjs, json, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-controller

This is the JSON and controllers im using:

JSON Format:

```
{"tomcatLogDir":"C:\\apache-tomcat-7.0.70\\logs","tomcatLogs":["1.log","2.log","3.log"]}
```

Factory:

```
app.factory('filesFactory', [ '$http', 
                                        function($http) {
                                            return $http.get("http://"+ boxIP +":"+ boxPort +"/monitorTool/rest/toolservice/files")
                                                .success(function(data) {
                                                    return data;
                                                }).error(function(err) {
                                                    return err;
                                                })
                                            } ]);
```

Controller:

```
app.controller('tomcatLogDirController', [ '$scope', 'filesFactory',
                                            function($scope, jsonFactory) {
                                                jsonFactory.success(function(data) {
                                                        $scope.tomcatDir = data;
                                        });
                                    }]);
```

HTML:

```
    <div ng-controller="tomcatLogDirController">
        <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="x in tomcatDir">
                <a ng-href="{{'file?name=' + tomcatDir.tomcatLogDir + x.tomcatLogs}}">{{x.tomcatLogs}}</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

So i tried this, and the tomcatLogs don't appear they seem to not get loaded into the html.

What I'm I doing wrong, I'm i doing the wrong call to the JSON file?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your controller, you should have `'filesFactory'` instead of `jsonFactory`

It should have parameters correctly,

```
app.controller('tomcatLogDirController', [ '$scope', 'filesFactory',
                                            function($scope, filesFactory) {
```

**EDIT**

```
  <ul>
   <li ng-repeat="x in tomcatDir.tomcatLogs">
     <a >{{x}}</a>
   </li>
  </ul>
```

**[DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/sY3cQllfpE34mVUaLHio?p=preview)**

Comment: How do i call the tomcatLogs in the ng-repeat?

Comment: Check the sample\

Comment: Thanks, now if i want to concatenate `ng-href="{{'file?name=' + tomcatDir.tomcatLogDir + x.tomcatLogs}}"` correctly cause it doesn't show the `\1.log` at the end of the link

Comment: <a ng-href="{{'file?name=' + tomcatDir.tomcatLogDir + x}}">{{x}}</a>

Comment: Thanks again for your wisdom! :)